# How to choose categorical variables?

Tags: pandas

I'm new to modeling
I have a lot of functions and I have to separate them into discrete and continuous functions. There are only type tips on the internet

```
Categorical = np.where(df.dtypes = np.object)[0]
Categorical
```

Then I have only categorical functions resulting from the format, and I mean real categorical functions. Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: Please see this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to ask a minimum reproducible example

Comment: I have about 40 variables, some have 'object' format, others have 'int64' format.
These 'int64' variables have only a few unique states, so I also think they are categorial.
I need an easy method to AUTOMATICALLY catch discrete variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if you don't want to play in a loop, just use this simple line of code:

```
categorical_fun = np.where((df2.dtypes == np.object)|(df2.nunique() <= 10))[0]
categorical_fun
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whether a variable should be considered "discrete" or "continuous" is dependent on the variable and the use case.

To count the number of distinct values a variable takes in your `dataframe` - you can use the `pd.Series.nunique` or `pd.Series.value_counts` functions and decide to treat a variable as discrete or continuous based on the output.

`pandas` does come with a dedicated `dtype` called *category* which might be helpful - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']}) 
In [3]: df                                                                                                                                                    
Out[3]: 
   A  B
0  1  a
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  b

In [4]: df.A.value_counts()                                                                                                                                   
Out[4]: 
1    2
3    1
2    1
Name: A, dtype: int64

In [5]: df['B'].nunique()                                                                                                                                     
Out[5]: 2

In [6]: df['B'].unique()                                                                                                                                      
Out[6]: array(['a', 'b'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know that these categorical data are either in 'object' format or have a limited number of unique values, use a double condition and let the code show you these columns.
Suppose you think that categorical variables have up to 10 unique values, then:

```
a,b = df2.shape     #<- ile mamy kolumn
b

print('ONLY DISCRETE FUNCTION')
print('----------------------')
for i in range(1,b):
    i = df2.columns[i]
    f = df2[i].dtypes
    h = df2[i].nunique()

    if f == np.object or h<=10:
        print(i,"---",f,"---",h)
```

[image]